# How to mute audio of a video stream

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am new to android app development. I have a project in which i need to decode audio of a video stream. My app would take a video file and mute its audio. I have already tried to get byte code of a video file placed in the resources of my app but manipulation of this byte code is yet not figured out.

Kindly guide me. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by mute the audio? Mute is the feature depending on the sound player. If you don't want audio at all, you can extract the video only from your file and play it which wont have any audio. If this is not the case, can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: What i mean is that in my app i would play an online stream that would have audio enabled but at a certain event i want to disable the audio.

Comment: generally for making the audio mute in between you need to play with your sound device only i guess rather then the stream/video itself. If you stream your content from the scratch using raw frames and you know the specific timeframes where audio needs to be muted, you can handle it in a different way but the best shot is to control the sound playing device in your application.

Comment: Thankyou NitinG. And one more thing, what is the best way to display a live stream in app? I have been trying to do this using VideoView but no luck yet.

Comment: one of the alternative is to use imageview and play the images at a particular fps using ffmpeg library. It works decently. BTW what is the issue while using VideoView?